How to use the functions 'new_edge' and 'new_node' with Ecoinvent activities?
I've gone through the tutorial "1 - The supply chain graph" where @cmutel demonstrates how to build a simple product system (and do an LCA of it) by manually creating activities, saving them as nodes, and then linking them as edges.
Could anyone provide some hints/link to a tutorial on how a product system could be modeled with EI activities and the functions new_node and new_edge? Many thanks in advance!
Here is an extract of my code:
bd.projects.set_current("Simple_PS")

db = bd.Database("SPS01")
db.register()

# example of some activities I fetched from the ecoinvent DB that I'd like to include in my product system
code_El_PT = ei_db.search("market for electricity, medium voltage PT")[0]["code"]
act_El_PT = ei_db.get(code_El_PT)
code_calcium_nitrate = ei_db.search("calcium nitrate production RER")[0]['code']
act_calcium_nitrate = ei_db.get(code_calcium_nitrate)

data = { # this would be my main node (reference flow / FU), as the bike in cmutel example, and EI activities would be linked to it 
    'code': 'PS_main',
    'name': 'PS_main',
    'location': 'DK',
    'unit': 'PS_main'
}
PS_main = db.new_node(**data)
PS_main.save()

Then I tried several different commands to make EI activities as nodes
Ex01:
el = db.new_node(act_El_PT)
el.save()

Ex02:
el = db.new_node(act_El_PT, act_El_PT['name'])
el.save()

Ex03:
data = {act_El_PT}
el = db.new_node(**data)
el.save()

But nothing worked.

First, create nodes for the EI activities. Then, create the nodes.
Code example:
# 1. create the nodes    

    el_data = {
            'code': act_El_PT['code'],
            'name': act_El_PT['name'],
            'location': act_El_PT.get('location', ''),  # Handle potential missing location
            'unit': act_El_PT.get('unit', '')  # Handle potential missing unit
        }
        el = db.new_node(**el_data)
        el.save()
    
    calcium_nitrate_data = {
        'code': act_calcium_nitrate['code'],
        'name': act_calcium_nitrate['name'],
        'location': act_calcium_nitrate.get('location', ''),  # Handle potential missing location
        'unit': act_calcium_nitrate.get('unit', '')  # Handle potential missing unit
    }
    calcium_nitrate = db.new_node(**calcium_nitrate_data)
    calcium_nitrate.save()
    
## 2. Create the edges
    PS_main.new_edge(
        amount=2.5, 
        type='technosphere',
        input=el
    ).save()
    PS_main.new_edge(
        amount=4, 
        type='technosphere',
        input=calcium_nitrate
    ).save()

## 3. Verify that worked

    df = bd.Database("SPS01").nodes_to_dataframe()
    df


    df = bd.Database("SPS01").edges_to_dataframe()
    df

    
    list(PS_main.technosphere())


This answer is probably wrong because I get EmpityBiosphere traceback when I run the LCA calculations on PD_main.

the answer is indeed wrong. You shouln't create activities/node from existing activities like this. If you want a copy use the copy method

A way to think about an LCA database is to think activities / elementary flows are nodes of a graph, and the exchanges are the edges connecting the nodes. If you've imported ecoinvent you already have the activities/nodes. You don't need to create them again. You can certainly create copies, or create new edges/exchanges between nodes/activities. You can run db.new_node(**data) or db.new_activity(**data), whatever sounds more natural to you. Internally one method calls the other.
